# Android send data from main UI thread to another thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, android-asynctask

I need to send some data from the main thread to another thread. I've already read a lot of materials on threads, asynctasks and handlers but maybe they created some confusion to me. I read that I need to create a Handler to my 'second thread' so that I can send messages from the main thread to it (for now I'm not worrying about send back anything to the main thread).

I need the second thread to connect to a server (via socket) and send some date on some user events. I'm trying to do it in an efficiently manner (do not open/close unnecessary socket connections). So I'm wondering where should I put my open socket command? Also, in my handler's handleMessage() method I need a reference to the socket output stream in order to send data to server.

I have currently the following code:

```
protected void initThread(){
    this.thread = new HandlerThread(WorkerHandler.class.getCanonicalName()){        

        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            try{
                handler = new WorkerHandler(getLooper());
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }               
        }

    };
    this.thread.start();
}
```

The method initThread() is called in the onCreate() method of my activity.

Here follows the code of my custom handler class:

```
public class WorkerHandler extends Handler {

protected Socket socket;
protected BufferedWriter writer;

public WorkerHandler(Looper looper) throws Exception{
    super(looper);      
    this.socket = new Socket("192.168.1.7", 5069);
    this.writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(this.socket.getOutputStream(), "utf-8"));

}

public BufferedWriter getWriter(){
    return this.writer;
}

public Socket getSocket(){
    return this.socket;
}

@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    Draw draw = (Draw) msg.obj;
    if (draw != null){          
        if (getWriter() != null){
            try{
                getWriter().write(DrawUtil.toJson(draw)+"\n");
                getWriter().flush();
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

And again, in my activity, I trigger the sendDataToServer() method

```
protected void sendDataToServer(){
    Draw draw = new Draw(getFlowType(), getID(), getSeq(), Calendar.getInstance(), startX, startY, endX, endY);
    if (getWorkerHandler() != null){
        Message msg = getWorkerHandler().obtainMessage();
        msg.obj = draw;
        getWorkerHandler().sendMessage(msg);
    }       
}
```

But my reference to the WorkerHandler object is always null. I'm pretty sure I misunderstood some concept... Could you please give me some hints?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Show the code for `getWorkerHandler()` in your activity.

Comment: Thanks @DavidWasser! It actually returns this.handler. The reference is set in the initThread() method inside the run() method of the second thread.

Comment: I see your problem, just formulating my answer. Gimme a few minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it this way. You've created your second Thread by using `HandlerThread`. A `HandlerThread` is a `Thread` that has a `Looper`. So that is what is going on in the `run()` method of `HandlerThread`. It is running the looper loop. That means that the `run()` method in the `HandlerThread` will only complete when the `Looper` exits.

In your `initThread()` method you wrote:

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run(); // <-- This call runs the Looper loop and doesn't complete!!
        try{
            handler = new WorkerHandler(getLooper());
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }               
    }
```

You can see that your overridden `run()` method first calls `super.run()`. This runs the looper loop and doesn't complete. So the rest of your code in `initThread()` never executes.

If you want to use a `HandlerThread()` then you can't mess with its `run()` method. If you want it to do stuff for you then you'll need to post messages (or `Runnable`s) to it, and do your work there. Here's an example:

```
    HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("myHandlerThread");
    handlerThread.start();
    // Now get the Looper from the HandlerThread so that we can create a Handler that is attached to
    // the HandlerThread
    // NOTE: This call will block until the HandlerThread gets control and initializes its Looper
    Looper looper = handlerThread.getLooper();
    // Create a handler attached to the background message processing thread
    handler = new Handler(looper, this);
```

Now you can post messages and `Runnable`s to the "handler". In this example, the messages will be processed by an overridden `handleMessage()` method of the creating class.

**EDIT: Provide code example for the Handler callback**

You can use your `WorkerHandler` class to handle the callbacks if you modify it like this (I've changed the name to `Worker` because it isn't really a `Handler`, it just implements the `Handler.Callback` interface):

```
public class Worker implements Handler.Callback {

    protected Socket socket;
    protected BufferedWriter writer;

    public Worker() throws Exception{    
        this.socket = new Socket("192.168.1.7", 5069);
        this.writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(this.socket.getOutputStream(), "utf-8"));
    }

    public BufferedWriter getWriter(){
        return this.writer;
    }

    public Socket getSocket(){
        return this.socket;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Draw draw = (Draw) msg.obj;
        if (draw != null){          
            if (getWriter() != null){
                try{
                    getWriter().write(DrawUtil.toJson(draw)+"\n");
                    getWriter().flush();
                }catch(IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you need to create an instance of this `Worker` class and pass it as the callback argument when you create the `Handler`. In your activity do:

```
    HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("myHandlerThread");
    handlerThread.start();
    Looper looper = handlerThread.getLooper();
    // Create an instance of the class that will handle the messages that are posted
    //  to the Handler
    Worker worker = new Worker();
    // Create a Handler and give it the worker instance to handle the messages
    handler = new Handler(looper, worker);
```

Comment: Thank you very much @DavidWasser! I understand your point and I've fixed my code (took out the overwritten run() method on my initThreadMethod)... but now, when I run the program, I get a NetworkOnMainThreadException! Any hint?

Comment: The handler is "attached" to the thread that creates it, right? So this might be the problem... I'm creating the handler in the UI thread (after the handlerThread.start())

Comment: That depends on how you create the `Handler`. If you look at my example, using `handler = new Handler(looper, this)`, the handler is attached to the `HandlerThread`, not the main thread. You can create the `Handler` in the UI thread, you just need to make sure that it is attached to the other `Thread`.

Comment: Where should I put the initialization of the new Handler inside the Thread (in which method)? Or, if I use my current code (creating the handler in the main thread) when calling `handler = new Handler(looper,this)` `this` is a callable object... what should I exactly put there? I tried to pass a reference to my thread, but - as I expected - it's not the right object. Thanks again for your patience...

Comment: You don't initialize the handler inside the Thread. You initialize the handler outside the thread (in this case, I've done it in the main thread after creating the thread. In my example, the call to `new Handler(looper, this)` is used because the calls to `handleMessage()` are handled in the calling class (`this`). You need to give the handler a method to handle the messages. In my case I've passed `this` because my class implements the `Handler.Callback` interface and I have a `handleMessage()` method in my class. What you can do is to use your `WorkerHandler` class for that, if you want.

Comment: I've taken your code and modified it a bit to fit into this architecture. Have a look at my edit. I didn't compile it, so there may be some small errors in it, but you should get the idea.

Comment: Thanks again @DavidWassen! It works! I just changed a small piece of code because, since the Worker() class is called inside the UI Thread, I could not have the socket initialization in the constructor. I've moved it instead to the handleMessage method... if they are null I create them! Thank you, thank you and thank you!

Comment: Sure. No problem. Glad to be of assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You could solve it using standard Java ways for consumer / producer problems, i.e. a `BlockingQueue` consumed by a thread and any amount of threads that produce data.

```
public class SendingWorker {
    private final BlockingQueue<Draw> sendQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Draw>();
    private volatile Socket socket;

    public void start() {
        thread.start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        // interrupt so waiting in queue is interrupted
        thread.interrupt();
        // also close socket if created since that can block indefinitely
        Socket socket = this.socket;
        if (socket != null) {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    // adding to queues is thread safe
    public void send(Draw draw) {
        sendQueue.add(draw);
    }

    private final Runnable task = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 8000);
                OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
                while (true) {
                    Draw draw = sendQueue.take();
                    out.write(draw);
                    out.flush();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // handle 
            } finally {
                // cleanup
            }
        }
    };
    private final Thread thread = new Thread(task);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @zapl! I'll try out your solution and I'll let you know. Best!

Answer (score 0):

You can get values through broadcast receiver......as follows, First create your own IntentFilter as,

```
Intent intentFilter=new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction("YOUR_INTENT_FILTER");
```

Then create inner class BroadcastReceiver as,

```
    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    /** Receives the broadcast that has been fired */
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction()=="YOUR_INTENT_FILTER"){
           //HERE YOU WILL GET VALUES FROM BROADCAST THROUGH INTENT EDIT YOUR TEXTVIEW///////////
           String receivedValue=intent.getStringExtra("KEY");
        }
    }
};
```

Now Register your Broadcast receiver in onResume() as,

```
registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
```

And finally Unregister BroadcastReceiver in onDestroy() as,

```
unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
```

Now the most important part...You need to fire the broadcast from background thread to send values..... so do as,

```
Intent i=new Intent();
i.setAction("YOUR_INTENT_FILTER");
i.putExtra("KEY", "YOUR_VALUE");
sendBroadcast(i);
```

....cheers :)

Comment: Not sure why you thought BroadcastReceiver's `onReceive()` is executed on non-UI thread